# How do I put the data received from an API response into elements of an HTML file when I'm working with express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

This is the server file, **app.js** -

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const omdbapi = new(require('omdbapi'))('api_key');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app.html');
});

app.get('/query', function(req, res) {
  let movieId = req.query.id;
  let title = req.query.title;
  omdbapi.get({
    id: movieId
  }).then(response => {
    renderDetails(response);
    res.send(response);
  }).catch(console.error);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(params) {
  console.log('Server running at 3000.');
});
```

I have the **app.html** that I send when the root of the URL is accessed, which is working fine. A **styles.css** file which is also working as expected. And finally, I have a **result.html** which looks something like this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Result</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="movie-title">Dummy Title</h2>
  <img class="movie-poster" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Dummy Image">
  <p class=""movie-year>Year</p>
  <p>Rated</p>
  <p>Released</p>
  <p>Runtime</p>
  <p>Genre</p>
  <p>Director</p>
  <p>Writer</p>
  <p>Actors</p>
  <p>Plot</p>
  <p>Country</p>
  <p>Awards</p>
  <p>IMDB Ratings</p>
  <p>Type</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to know how I can incorporate all the data I received from the API response in various elements of this **result.html** file.

In **app.html**, I have created a movie card, when the card is clicked, it will trigger get request for the `/query` route which results in getting data successfully from the API and storing it into the `response` object. Now I want to figure out a way to incorporate all that data in their respective elements in the **result.html** file.

I know there's a way to use EJS, but I haven't started learning EJS yet, so I would like to know if there is any other way besides that which I can use now.

Comment: Instead of having a `result.html` file, you can have a template element in `app.html` and fill it with the data. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#examples

Comment: There are two ways I can think of, one is to directly respond with the html using string templates from within the `/query`'s request handler which will be purely on the Express server, another one is you host the html somewhere and use AJAX/fetch. If you want the pure backend solution, save your sanity and consider using views like Handlebars for templating or EJS as you mentioned :)